# What is mortality rate in dragon ball and why they considered destroying universes for that?

Tags: dragon-ball-super

I'm not able to understand what is the meaning of mortality rate as referred in episode 84 when it is said that universe 7 has low mortality rate so what they meant with that and why they considered destroying universes for that.

Comment: I don't remember this term. I think it's explained differently in subtitles. IRL, that term refers to chance of death.

Answer (score 1):

As quoted in Pablo's [answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/47527), the Mortal Level is a measurement of the quality of the mortals used by the Kings of All.  We're not really told exactly what goes into deciding this value, other than a singular data point from the manga (which did not happen in the anime, however, to my recollection):

> In the manga Universe 7 gets enough of a score boost to rank-up (a single position) thanks to 17's wish to bring back all of the destroyed universes. So setting aside selfish desires to save things beyond yourself that normally would never affect you is apparently one of the dimensions for evaluation.

We're also not explicitly told *why* this measure was developed, etc.  But the implications are clear: the universes were created *for a purpose*, and that purpose is not simply to exist and unfold in whatever way they desire.  The creator god(s) are not simply watchmakers and observers, but are actively engaged in their creation for whatever that purpose is.  That purpose is evidently measured, at least in part, by Mortal Level.  Universes which systematically fail to live up to that purpose are subject to destruction.  Perhaps the Kings of All had a motive similar to the creator gods in the Tenchi series: to see if they were powerful enough to create something more powerful than themselves.  If so, maybe that's why Whis was always hoping Goku and/or Vegeta could achieve Ultra Instinct.  Perhaps they just wanted companions and entertainment the angels couldn't provide, and created universes so that they might produce such beings, and universes that seem incapable of doing so can be discarded.  Perhaps it is all just a form of entertainment, as we have at times seen the Kings of All acting bored and wanting something interesting to happen.  In which case the Mortal Level might just be an arbitrary measuring stick created simply to give a sense of challenge and excitement: see how high the universes can go, see what you can do to get a higher score, but with no purpose *beyond* the score.  Universes that do poorly could then be discarded, like one might delete or reset a video game save that doesn't go as well as one desired.  Got caught pickpocketing in Skyrim?  Reload and try again!

One way or another the Kings of All are meant to be alien: their values and goals are fundamentally different from our own, or from (most of) those inhabiting the universes.

Answer (score -1):

According to [Dragon Ball Wikia - Mortal Level](http://dragonball.wikia.com/wiki/Mortal_Level)

> Mortal Level (人間 レベル, Ningen Reberu, lit. "mortal level") is the score
>   that the Zeno and Future Zeno use to rank the twelve universes. It is
>   a measuring of the average development, or "quality", of the mortals
>   existing in a universe. The Mortal Level of a universe is directly
>   related to the effectiveness of the jobs of its Supreme Kais and Gods
>   of Destruction (allowing and promoting the creation and development of
>   adequate civilizations and elimination of inadequate ones).

Answer (score -1):

Mortal level is how many mortals there are in that universe.. Beerus as a god of destruction in is some.. But he just destroys planets because there food don't live up to his liking.. That's a big number of mortals gone each planet.. And planet is a living thing to.. His Jon is to destroy bag or sumthin that is not meant to happen ext .. The kais are meant to guide .. 7th universe is good at that would be better if elder Kai didn't get locked in sword by beerus .. We know why . Because if a Kai dies God dies as well.. As for energy of the universe is more dark because of 'll the ev-".. Universe let's say 2 is it is about love so a lot of alive people and good energy good mortal rating.. Same with 11 ... they keep there universe safe from wrong doers as top would say corny.. The clown should be a little bad tho .. Was disappointed..  But ya that's the meaning ..  .. Like look at frost and freiza.. Bcus of frost methods there are more mortals.. But deep down dark .. Freiza just kills everything.. Dark out and in no shock that there almost down